# Need plugin to overwrite default title

Tags: solr, nutch

Im trying to write a plugin for Nutch based on http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/07/nutch-custom-plugin-to-parse-and-add.html to get a custom title finder.

This works well, and storing extracted titles in new field is no problem. But I want to use it in Solr instead of default title. The problem is Solr needs multivalued fields as I have 2 title fields.

metadata.remove("title");

didnt work.

I really want to use the new title instead of the default one created by Nutch. Any suggestions?

Comment: doc.removeField("title"); does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your title in a different field, thus it will be handled properly ?

Comment: Because then I would have to store content from PDFs e.g. also in a different field. If you know how to do that, then do share.

Comment: not sure what you mean by content from PDF ? Although I haven't tried I guess in the indexing plugin you can get the text (raw) of the PDF. Of course you need a method to extract the information your looking for as this is just raw text, all formatting is gone

Comment: Thinking twice at your question... for storing/indexing PDF content  in a different index, you need to know that this is PDF document at indexing time. So I would if I can store some meta-data at parsing time indicating PDF type and retrieve it at indexing time to put that data in specific index.